TV detective/criminal series with episode about murderer who tattoos date of death on victim's belly
I'm looking for the name of the TV series with an episode that shows a dead body in the morgue with the date of death tattooed on the belly.
The team is short of time because other victims found with the tattoo of their death date make them believe that the next victim is about to be murdered that same day...
I think there are four agents, one of them a woman, in the team. I can't find what series it is!

Marco, if you're editing your question, please log in to the website first, otherwise we can't know for sure you are the one editing it :)

This is a storyline from the series The Rookie It took place over the course of several episodes.
episode The Dark Side

At the police station, Dyer tells John Nolan that the LAPD was going to find two more bodies at the next gravesite, which proves to be true as the team recovers two more bodies at Rosalind's second gravesite, with the second body once again being much fresher. They determine that the first body was killed exactly six months prior, and that the second new body was killed three months prior; each body has a tattoo with the date of their death on their skin. The police then determine that the next victim was going to be killed that day.
....
With Dyer being uncooperative, the team is forced to find the third victim on their own, which Nolan and Harper succeed in doing. However, the killer manages to escape before they can catch him.

In a later episode Day of Death a police woman is kidnapped, has her day of death tattooed on her abdomen and is buried alive. The police are in a race against time to find her.

This seems a likely match

You mcan accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark
